# SQL - extract XML with multiple nodes

Tags: sql, xml

I'm trying to extract data from XML in my SQL column that has multiple lists of data in them that are stored in two different ways.

I'm only familiar with using cross apply to get a single list but how do I do it for multiple nodes, especially if they are in different structures?

```
DECLARE @XML XML = 
'
<root>
<Bundle name="x">
<Profiles>
    <Profile>
        <ApplicationRef>
            <Reference class="a" name="application1"/>
        </ApplicationRef>
        <Constraints>
            <Filter property="e" value="ent1"/>
            <Filter property="e" value="ent2"/>
        </Constraints>
    </Profile>
    <Profile>
        <ApplicationRef>
            <Reference class="a" name="application2"/>
        </ApplicationRef>
        <Constraints>
            <Filter property="e" value="entA"/>
            <Filter property="e" value="entB"/>
        </Constraints>
    </Profile>
</Profiles>
</Bundle>
<Bundle name="y">
<Profiles>
    <Profile>
        <ApplicationRef>
            <Reference class="a" name="application1"/>
        </ApplicationRef>
        <Constraints>
            <Filter property="e" value="ent3"/>
            <Filter property="e" value="ent4"/>
        </Constraints>
    </Profile>
    <Profile>
        <ApplicationRef>
            <Reference class="a" name="application3"/>
        </ApplicationRef>
        <Constraints>
            <Filter property="m" value="entA">
                <Value>
                    <List>
                        <String>this</String>
                        <String>that</String>
                        <String>thus</String>
                    </List>
                </Value>
            </Filter>
        </Constraints>
    </Profile>
</Profiles>
</Bundle>
</root>
'

SELECT
    Bun = XC.value('@name', 'VARCHAR(200)'),
    App =  XC2.value('@name', 'VARCHAR(200)'),
    Ent =  XC3.value('.', 'VARCHAR(200)')
FROM 
    @Xml.nodes('//Bundle') AS XT(XC)
CROSS APPLY
    xc.nodes('//Bundle/Profiles/Profile/ApplicationRef/Reference') AS XT2(XC2)
CROSS APPLY
    xc.nodes('//Bundle/Profiles/Profile/Constraints/Filter/Value/List/String') AS XT3(XC3)
```

I don't mind if the ent data is in a single column, but the Bun and App Columns need to different

| Bun | App | Ent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | application1 | ent1 |
| x | application1 | ent2 |
| x | application2 | entA |
| x | application2 | entB |
| y | application1 | ent3 |
| y | application1 | ent4 |
| y | application3 | this |
| y | application3 | that |
| y | application3 | thus |

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, here is what you are looking for.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<root>
    <Bundle name="x">
        <Profiles>
            <Profile>
                <ApplicationRef>
                    <Reference class="a" name="application1"/>
                </ApplicationRef>
                <Constraints>
                    <Filter property="e" value="ent1"/>
                    <Filter property="e" value="ent2"/>
                </Constraints>
            </Profile>
            <Profile>
                <ApplicationRef>
                    <Reference class="a" name="application2"/>
                </ApplicationRef>
                <Constraints>
                    <Filter property="e" value="entA"/>
                    <Filter property="e" value="entB"/>
                </Constraints>
            </Profile>
        </Profiles>
    </Bundle>
    <Bundle name="y">
        <Profiles>
            <Profile>
                <ApplicationRef>
                    <Reference class="a" name="application1"/>
                </ApplicationRef>
                <Constraints>
                    <Filter property="e" value="ent3"/>
                    <Filter property="e" value="ent4"/>
                </Constraints>
            </Profile>
            <Profile>
                <ApplicationRef>
                    <Reference class="a" name="application3"/>
                </ApplicationRef>
                <Constraints>
                    <Filter property="m" value="entA">
                        <Value>
                            <List>
                                <String>this</String>
                                <String>that</String>
                                <String>thus</String>
                            </List>
                        </Value>
                    </Filter>
                </Constraints>
            </Profile>
        </Profiles>
    </Bundle>
</root>';

SELECT  p.value('@name', 'VARCHAR(200)') AS bundle_name
    , c.value('(ApplicationRef/Reference/@name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)') AS app_name
    , d.value('(.)[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)') AS constraints_filter
FROM @Xml.nodes('/root/Bundle') t1(p)
CROSS APPLY p.nodes('Profiles/Profile') AS t2(c)
CROSS APPLY c.nodes('Constraints/Filter/@value') AS t3(d)
UNION ALL
SELECT  p.value('@name', 'VARCHAR(200)') AS bundle_name
    , c.value('(ApplicationRef/Reference/@name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)') AS app_name
    , e.value('(text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)') AS constraints_filter_list
FROM @Xml.nodes('/root/Bundle') t1(p)
CROSS APPLY p.nodes('Profiles/Profile') AS t2(c)
CROSS APPLY c.nodes('Constraints/Filter/Value/List/String') AS t4(e);
```

**Output**

| bundle_name | app_name | constraints_filter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | application1 | ent1 |
| x | application1 | ent2 |
| x | application2 | entA |
| x | application2 | entB |
| y | application1 | ent3 |
| y | application1 | ent4 |
| y | application3 | entA |
| y | application3 | this |
| y | application3 | that |
| y | application3 | thus |

Comment: that was perfect, thank you so much